# Using independence to compute exponential order statistics

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, order-statistics, exponential-distribution

I am in a stochastic processes course, and I am trying to apply a result about the minimum of iid exponentials.

Here is the result:

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be independent exponential random variables with rates $\lambda_i$. $I = j$ if $X_j < min_{k \neq j}X_k$

Then $P(I = j) = \frac{\lambda_j}{\sum_\lambda}$

Here is the problem to which I am applying it.

Two patients are waiting for kidney transplants; each will die in exponential time, with the respective rates being $\mu_A, \mu_B$. Kidneys become available as a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$. A will receive the first kidney unless A dies before the first kidney becomes available. What is the probability that neither A nor B gets a kidney?

I am approaching the problem the following way.

If neither A nor B gets a kidney, then $S_1$, the arrival time of the first kidney, must be greater than $D_A$ and $D_B$, the times of death of $A$ and $B$.

All three are exponential, and independent.

Therefore, $Pr(D_A < S_1, D_B < S_1)$ can be treated as $D_A$ being the minimum of exponential random variables $\{D_A, S_1\}$, and similarly for $\{D_B, S_1\}$.

$Pr(D_A < S_1, D_B < S_1) = Pr(D_A~ \text{min of} \{D_A, S_1\}) Pr(D_B ~\text{min of} \{D_B, S_1\})$

$= \big{(}\frac{\mu_A}{\mu_A + \lambda}\big{)}\big{(}\frac{\mu_B}{\mu_B + \lambda}\big{)}$

Is this reasoning sound?

Comment: The two events are not independent here. You may try to apply law of total probability by conditioning on $S_1$ first, then they are conditionally independent.

Comment: Why are they not independent? How would I check? How does knowledge of whether one patient dies before the first kidney affect the probability the other patient dies?

Comment: Although the random variables are independent, $S_1$ appear in both event and thus it will be more counter-intuitive if they are independent. Actually in this case the knowledge of one patient dies before the kidney arrives implies the kidney is more likely to arrive late, so the other patient is also more likely to die before the kidney arrive.

Answer (score 1):

$\big{(}\frac{\mu_A}{\mu_A + \lambda}\big{)}\big{(}\frac{\mu_B}{\mu_B + \lambda}\big{)}$ is unlikely to be the probability that $S_1$ is the maximum.  For example, if $\mu_A = \mu_B = \lambda$ that expression would give $\frac14$ when by symmetry it should be $\frac13$

If $S_1=s$, then the conditional probability it is the maximum is $\left(1-e^{-\mu_A s}\right)\left(1-e^{-\mu_B s}\right)$

So the overall probability that $S_1$ is the maximum is $$\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda s}\left(1-e^{-\mu_A s}\right)\left(1-e^{-\mu_B s}\right)\, ds \\ =  1 - \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+ \mu_A} -\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+ \mu_B} +\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+ \mu_A+ \mu_B}$$

and this is $\frac13$ when $\mu_A = \mu_B = \lambda$